# use dictionary comprehension to iterate over a list of list

Tags: python, bioinformatics

what is the correct syntax for doing a list comprehension over a list of list? I am using a dict. comprehensions to convert one value to another in a list of list, but I cant get it to do the entire list of lists. Here is what I have:

```
v_list = [['A'], ['V']]
test = {codon for (codon,AA) in translation.items() for aa in v_list if AA == aa}
```

This line of code works if v_list is just a normal list, but I need to keep the letters in separate lists within the list.

Using

```
v_list[0][0]
```

works, but I need a solution that automatically iterates over all lists in list and not just ones I hard-code into the program.

Thanks!

EDIT
Sorry for the confusion with this question. my dictionary looks something like this:

```
translation = {'TTT': 'F', 'TCT': 'S', 'TAT': 'Y', 'TGT': 'C',
                 'TTC': 'F', 'TCC': 'S', 'TAC': 'Y', 'TGC': 'C',
                 'TTA': 'L'}
```

and my inputs look like this:

```
in = [['S'],['F']]
```

so I wanted to pull all the 'S' into in[0][0] and all the 'F's into in[1][1]. But 'in' is of unknown length, something the user enters as a parsed object.  So my output would hopefully look like this:

```
out = [['TCT', 'TCC'], ['TTT', 'TTC']]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide the entire code,  e.g. also `translation`.

Comment: Are the lists within your list always going to be a single element? If so just reference the first element in the list i.e. 

test = {codon for (codon,AA) in translation.items() for aa in v_list if AA == aa[0]}

Comment: that's not a dict comprehension, that's a _set_ comprehension.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre, but from what ive read this is how you do a dictionary comprehension, what is the correct dict comprehension?

Comment: something like: `{k:v for k,v in somedict.items() if "something" in k}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use something like:

```
{codon for codon, AA in translation.items() for bb in v_list for aa in bb if AA == aa}
```

You can add multiple levels of `for x in y` to iterate through multiple levels of a nested structure. A few simple examples:

```
a =  [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]     # unwrapping a list two levels deep
[c for b in a for c in b]  # gives [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

a = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]     # a list of lists of lists
[d for b in a for c in b for d in c]  # gives [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Obviously you can overdo this and things get hard to track when you do so use with caution.

Comment: `for (codon,AA) in translation.items()` => `for codon,AA in translation.items()` no need for parens.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting a "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bb' referenced before assignment" any tips?

Comment: @avigil you need to swap both `for` loops (difficult to test without the real data!!)

Comment: right I swapped the `for`! fixed, should be `for bb in v_list for aa in bb`

Comment: added a trivial example to demonstrate with some toy data

Answer (score 0):

### Nested List Output

Working off the OP specs, namely

```
v_list = [['S'],['F']]
translation = {
    'TTT': 'F', 'TCT': 'S', 'TAT': 'Y', 'TGT': 'C', 'TTC': 'F', 
    'TCC': 'S', 'TAC': 'Y', 'TGC': 'C', 'TTA': 'L'
}

# expected output : [['TCT', 'TCC'], ['TTT', 'TTC']]
```

I think you'd want:

```
[[codon for codon, aa in translation.items() if aa in pp] for pp in v_list]
# [['TCT', 'TCC'], ['TTT', 'TTC']]
```

---

### Flat Set

If what you really want is a flat set (like [what @avigil answered with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437937/570918)), then I'd suggest the following, which only iterates through the `v_list` once, and some might find more readable:

```
amino_acids = {aa for pp in v_list for aa in pp}
{codon for codon, aa in translation.items() if aa in amino_acids}
# {'TCC', 'TCT', 'TTT', 'TTC'}
```